# How to update multiple values in one table column with just one query?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

My `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` table has a column `FieldValue` with two values that I would like to respectively change.

I want to change `value1` to `firstvalue` and `value2` to `secondvalue`.

My PHP/Joomla code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("UPDATE `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` SET `FieldValue` = 'firstvalue' WHERE `FieldValue` = 'value1'");
return $db->loadResult();

$db1 = JFactory::getDbo();
$db1->setQuery("UPDATE `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` SET `FieldValue` = 'secondvalue' WHERE `FieldValue` = 'value2'");
return $db1->loadResult();
```

Can this update be executed in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the queries like this:

```
UPDATE jwqt5_rsform_submission_values
SET FieldValue = CASE FieldValue
    WHEN 'value1' THEN 'firstvalue'
    WHEN 'value2' THEN 'secondvalue'
END
WHERE FieldValue IN ('value1', 'value2')
```